# How to call a method on an action event using lambda expression in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I'm learning JavaFx, so I started with a very basic database application using JDBC. I'm a web developer and I'm coming from Javascript and Typescript background. I'm trying to call a method on click of a button. That method will simply push a record in the database. I'll show you my code first.

**AddNewBranchRecord.java**

```
public class AddNewBranchRecord {

    public static void askInitialDetails() {
        Scene scene;
        final Stage stage = new Stage();

        Button doneButton;
        ...

        doneButton = new Button("Done");
        doneButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            DataService dataservice = new DataService();
            dataservice.insertRecord();
        });

        ...

        stage.setTitle("INITIAL DETAILS");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

And here's the data service class that will interact with oracle.

**DataService.java**

```
public class DataService {
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;

    DataService() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","tiger","scott");
            stmt=con.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public int insertRecord() {
        int success = 0;
        try {
            success=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into emp values(2, 'Tanzeel')");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

But the moment I press on *Done* button, it gives me this exception:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: tasktracker.DataService.insertRecord()Z

Why I'm getting this `NoSuchMethod` exception. Same code works if I put this code inside constructor of caller class directly. Is there something related to *synchronization*. I'm thinking like this because I'm from Javascript and Typescript background. I know Java and JS are two different languages. Please point out my mistakes.

I'm using `JDK 8`.

Comment: That looks like it shouldn’t happen - the only way I can see this happening is if the source files and compiled files are out of sync. Try cleaning and rebuilding the entire project in your IDE. As an aside, you almost certainly don’t want to create a new data service every time the button is pressed - create one once and reuse it.

Comment: Documentation of [`NoSuchMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html): "_Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class **no longer** has a definition of that method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can **only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed**_". You must not have recompiled the necessary files after making changes.

Comment: I'm using **Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2**

Comment: I used _Clean and build_ option. It worked. :-) 
And also I've removed `DataService dataservice = new DataService();` from _Done_ button and kept outside so that is is created only once. :-) thank you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this can occur is if the `DataService` class was compiled without the `addRecord()` method, and not recompiled since the `addRecord()` method was added. Usually, the compiler will ensure this doesn't happen (by automatically recompiling `DataService` when `AddNewBranchRecord` is compiled) but somehow it seems things have got out of sync.

Your best bet here is to remove all the generated class files and recompile your source code. Your IDE should have options to "Clean" and "Rebuild" the project, to accomplish these steps, respectively.

As an aside, you almost certainly don't want to create a new `DataService` (with its connection to the database) every time the user presses the button: move the call to the `DataService` constructor outside of the lambda expression (at least; you may want it scoped even broader).